# `flutter pub get` results in build runner error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I got this error out of the blue in Flutter mobile. When trying to run "flutter run" or "flutter pub get", I get this error

Because mapstest depends on build runner any which doesn't exist (could not find package build runner at https://pub.flutter-io.cn), version solving failed.

[image]

I tried fixing my proxy setting and it's all good I think. I tried downgrading flutter still doesn't work. `flutter doctor` is all good. I tried searching this error but no similar results gave me this.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong version of **build_runner**. Just run this command in the terminal :

```
dart pub add build_runner --dev
```

and then run this :

```
flutter pub run build_runner build
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is pretty simple. One of the packages you added requires another package to be installed - build_runner

https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner

Comment: added this to my dev_dependencies: build runner: ^2.1.8. but still doesnt work with same error :(

Comment: Nothing changed?